# Cannot redirect to another page with php session

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this code on my `login.php` that when the user and password matches with the database it will redirect to another page which requires logging in first before it can be accessible.

Here is my code in login

```
            $_SESSION['userlog'] = true;
            header('location: table.php');
```

And here is my code that requires logging in before the page become accessible.

```
           if(empty($_SESSION['userlog']))
           {
           header('LOCATION: login.php');
           }
```

The problem is when I click on login, it does not redirect in the next page. 
Any idea what is wrong or missing in my code?

Comment: header('Location: /login.php');
exit;

Comment: sir, it still cannot redirect to the next page after loggin in.

Comment: change your if condition like this `if(!$_SESSION['userlog'] == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare `session_start();` at the top of the page to enable sessions?

I would recommend validating if it was in fact set using `isset` and then empty

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userlog']) && empty($_SESSION['userlog']))
{
    header('LOCATION: login.php');
}
```

Comment: If you're using empty, you don't need to check if ```isset()```, ```empty()``` checks it for you. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): *A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals **FALSE***.